# Using Scikit-learn Pipelines, how can features be generated from time series data when the features depend on other rows?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, pipeline

**Here is a concrete example scenario:**

I want to train a classifier to predict whether a given stock will go up or down in price the next day.

**Here is how I want to do that:**

I have the daily close price of a particular stock over a given period of time. I want to generate features including the [exponential weighted moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average) and [price rate of change](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/pricerateofchange.asp). These calculations for a given day require the close prices of previous days. Then I want to calculate a target variable 1 or -1 indicating if the stock price went up or down the next day.

After generating the features and target, I want to split the data into train/test (or even train/validation/test) groups then train and test a classifier to predict the target.

Finally, I want to implement and execute these steps in an sklearn Pipeline for two main reasons: 1.) to easily manipulate the data flow and/or try different classifiers and 2.) to run a grid search to find good parameters to use in both the feature generation steps and classifier -- e.g. how many days should be taken into account to calculate the exponential weighted moving average or how many estimators should be used in the random forest classifier?

**Here is the issue I run into:**

From what I've read about sklearn Pipelines, I would need to create custom transformations and perhaps use FeatureUnion to generate the features. However, the examples I've seen all call `.fit(X_train, y_train)`, which runs each step in the Pipeline (including generating the features). But my features depend on other rows which may not be in X_train.

Comment: I'm unclear on your last sentence, that your features depend on rows outside of X_train... that seems antithetical to pipelining, which helps ensure there is no information bleed between train/test/validation. A simple example for illustration: if each row is a time step t_x, with t_0 in train and t_1 in test, add a new summary feature in training set that is (t_0+t_1)/2 has taught the model something unknowable about the future. I think including a moving weighted average is fine if you time-box it (train on Yr1, test on Yr2) and generate the averages only after your train/test split

Comment: @LaurenOldja The values should be calculated before train_test_split, because if you do a random split there is no a logical sequence between the rows of the dataset (neigther X, y).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation for [tsfresh](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/text/introduction.html). They even have an example for what you are looking for: [using time series transforms with sklearn pipelines'](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/text/sklearn_transformers.html)